# My first AVR C program- LED not blinking

Tags: avr, c, port

I created a simple program to be put onto a ATMega328P chip ([Datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/2503S.pdf)). I wrote my first program in ATMEL studio that I wanted to use to Blink an LED at a rate of 0.5Hz with extremely low power usage. Here's my code:

```
/*
 * GccApplication1.c
 *
 * Created: 11/12/2017 8:56:49 PM
 * Author : Brice
 */ 

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/power.h>

int main(void)
{
    clock_prescale_set(clock_div_128); //set the clock to use the 8MHz internal clock divided by 128 for an internal frequency of 250KHz, consumes 0.4mA while not sleeping.

    while (1) 
    {
        PORTD4 == 1;//Set pin 13 of the micro to high.
        _delay_ms(1000);
        PORTD4 == 0;//Set pin 13 of the micro to low;
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

What I expect this code to do to this micro-controller is to turn PORTD register 4 on for 1 second, then turn it off for a second.

currently, The PortD4 will not have any voltage changes to it, and remains grounded while the device is powered.

Any explanation of this would be appreciated!

For this instance, I'm using the Arduino Pro mini board for prototyping..

pin 4 of the Pro mini is connected to the common Anode of an RGB led, and the G pin of the LED is connected from a 510 Ohm resistor to GND. I've tested the wiring with a working arduino, and the led even lights at 3.3 Volts pretty brightly.

[image]

Comment: How do you have the LED wired up?

Comment: @RonBeyer pin 4 of the Pro mini is connected to the common Anode of an RGB led, and the G pin of the LED is connected from a 510 Ohm resistor to GND. I've tested the wiring with a working arduino, and the led even lights at 3.3 Volts pretty brightly.

Comment: `PORTD4 == 1; //CHECK IF pin 13 of the micro to high`. It doesn't set pin 13.

Comment: The datasheet you linked to is for the ATmega32, not the ATmega328! These are completly seperate processors. if you use the 32's datasheet as a reference, you're going to have a very hard time :-)  This is the right one: http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf

Comment: You need to enable compiler warnings. This code should not have compiled cleanly on any decent compiler.

Comment: @Lundin it didn't. The compiler complains about  F_cpu not being defined.

Comment: It should say something like "value computation is not used" and point at the bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int main(void)
{
    clock_prescale_set(clock_div_128); //set the clock to use the 8MHz internal clock divided by 128 for an internal frequency of 250KHz, consumes 0.4mA while not sleeping.

    while (1) 
    {
        PORTD4 == 1;//Set pin 13 of the micro to high.
        _delay_ms(1000);
        PORTD4 == 0;//Set pin 13 of the micro to low;
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

The problem is how you "set" the port, you are using `==` which is a comparison operator, not an assignment. Try just using `=`.

```
void main()
{
    DDRD = 0xFF;         //PD as output
    PORTD= 0x00;         //keep all LEDs off

    while(1)
    {
        PORTD &= 0b11110111;       //turn LED off
        _delay_ms(500);   //wait for half second
        PORTD |= 0b00001000;       //turn LED on 
        _delay_ms(500);   //wait for half second
    }        
}
```

You may also have to set the direction of the port somewhere. You would do this by setting the `DDRD` to be `0b00001000`, which should set Pin 4 of Port D to an output.

Comment: See my edit, you can write to `PORTD` directly, I showed the easiest way, but you can also do some bit manipulation, like `PORTD &= ~(1 << 4)`

Comment: No, I'll remove it, was just a typo that doesn't create a compiler error.

Comment: What does "|=" mean?

Comment: @KrishnShweta "Or Equals", it is another way of writing: `PORTD = PORTD | 0b00001000;`

Comment: I understand "==" and "=" concept but what's the need to write &= and |=?

Comment: @KrishnShweta It is a shortcut method, similar to `+=`, `++`, `-=`, `--`, etc. It is only short-hand, it compiles to the same thing. Personally I find it easier to read.

Comment: Hey, ron. I changed my code to what's in the question to no avail. I'm going to try a different board to see if I've got a bad one.

Comment: @tuskiomi See [this related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27081/using-avr-gcc-delay-ms-causes-chip-to-freeze?rq=1) since it seems you may have a similar issue.

Comment: @RonBeyer I figured out the issue- see my answer below, but I'm accepting yours because it is a more conventional solution.

Comment: @Krishn Shweta  it one of the basic operators. You need to learn C first. Without the C knowledge you cant program uC

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I know c and I'm learning embedded c nowadays :) I was actually asking what's the use of that when it is = instead of ==... My wording was wrong

Comment: I did my led blinking programs in embedded c, there i didn't use "& |" so i was wondering about it. @PeterJ_01

Answer (score 2):

Three problems:

1. If you're delay.h, you need to define the CPU speed. `#define F_CPU 8000000UL` in your case.
2. Port D needs to be set as an output by setting bit 4 in the DDRD register, typically before the superloop. `DDRD = 0b00010000`
3. PORTD4 is not how you access that port pin. You would use PORTD, similarly to how I demonstrated the DDRD register above. Personally, I would rewrite your superloop to:

   ```
   while (1) 
   {
       PORTD ^= 0b00010000;
       _delay_ms(1000);
   }
   ```

Comment: ^= is the xor op, right? Also, your bit  that you set differs from Ron's..  He uses the fourth from the left, why do you use the 4th from the right?

Comment: @tuskiomi that's it

Comment: Also, would I want to change the value of F_CPU since I'm using a clock divider to save power?

Comment: @tuskiomi Set F_CPU to whatever the clock frequency is in Hz. I wouldn't bother with the clock divider. The power savings at that level are negligible.

Answer (score -2):

In the end, the only thing that was wrong with the code were the fixes, but the canonical main problem of this situation was a faulty arduino board. a simple replacement fixed the issue.

Comment: Why the down votes?  This is what fixed the issue

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you aren't specific enough. What were the changes? This isn't a good answer

Comment: @laptop2d the arduino pro mini was bricked. I used a new one to fix the issue. what's not to understand?